# Viewpager in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

How could i create `ViewPager` in `both direction`. Is it possible ? If it possible how could i implement it.

I have created `viewpager` in single direction using the below code:

```
private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment0.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    }
```

Could anybody help me out..thanks!!

Comment: you can do it using this library and set pager orientation horizontal and vertical [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720276/error-including-android-directionalviewpager-jar-in-eclipse/14268702#14268702)

Comment: @sheetal thanks for your answer let me check !!

Comment: @AbhishekSabbarwal thanks for your answer let me check the link

Comment: sheetal i did not get any library there!!

Comment: @AbhishekSabbarwal i want to make viewpager in both direction not in single direction!!

Comment: click on the link answeres by MrMaffen...and your jar will be downloaded

Comment: sheetal i want to make viewpager in both direction not in single direction!!

Comment: yeah it will show in both horizontal and vertical direction...by default viewpager is horizontal..i have used this library

Comment: when you will define your viewpager set your viewpager.setOrientation horizontal or vertical at run time

Comment: @sheetal i dont want it horizontal and vertical i want it should slide in both direction left and as well as right!!

Comment: @priya2134412 yeas horizontal and vertical means the same..it will slide....i m not talking about orientation...why dont you try and speak! OR better go for a R&D

Comment: @priya2134412 first try before you write another comment

Comment: @sheetal i have tried but i didn't get could you help me out!!

Comment: @priya2134412 When I read this, and I see that you want it to slide "left to right and right to left", I am not sure I fully understand. Let's say your `List<Fragment>` contains 8 `Fragments`, do you want it to start in the middle, at 4, and then be able to scroll left or right from there?

Comment: @Asok thanks for your response and yes..right ..i want to do like that only!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay from what I understand, you have a list of `Fragments` in which you want the user to start in the middle of the `Pages`/`Fragments`, I have played with and tested the following code and it is working properly for me.

If you know the amount of `Fragments` and aren't dynamically changing the `Fragments` then this can be handled much more simply, but I am going off your code provided in the OP. Try it out:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // This is going to initialize our Fragment list
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.init();

        // Now we are going to determine the starting position
        int startPos = mSectionsPagerAdapter.getStartPosition();

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // AFTER we set the adapter we will define our start position
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(startPos);
    }
}
```

---

Now lets take a look at our `FragmentPagerAdapter`

I have added a couple methods to this class, the `init()` method, `setCount()`, and `getStartPosition()`.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int _count = 2;
    private int _start = 0;

    List<Fragment> fragments;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) { 
        super(fm);
    }

    public void init() {
        fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(new MyFragmentOne());
        fragments.add(new MyFragmentTwo());
        fragments.add(new MyFragmentThree());
        fragments.add(new MyFragmentFour());
        fragments.add(new MyFragmentFive());
        setCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return (fragments.size() >= position) ? fragments.get(position) : null;
    }

    // We have created this method to get the starting position
    // You might want to play around with this to make sure the returned
    // position fits what you want for odd numbered Fragment Pages
    public int getStartPosition() {
        _start = fragments.size() / 2;
        return Math.round(_start);
    }

    public void setCount() { this._count = fragments.size(); }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return this._count; }

    // You will need to change this to get the appropriate title per page    
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.company_select).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.companies_pending).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

*Please Note:* You did not provide examples of what you have tried so I have written code for you. StackOverflow isn't a place for this, in the future when something doesn't work give us what you have tried and we will try to help determine what went wrong.